# <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html"> with Dart 1.4.3, polymer 0.11.0-dev.6

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

i am using Dart 1.4.3, polymer 0.11.0-dev.6. now i have noticed that all my polymer-dart components give a warning about adding the link for polymer in the title above
to all polymer components. is this so. please also point me to some documentation about the changes of polymer version changes so i can keep abreast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/KIOlOvpr2-8

in each file where you define Polymer elements you should add as first import

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

and in the entry page you add these script tags instead of importing `polymer.html`

```dart
<!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
     not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
<script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. With this rapid changes in Dart/Polymer it is rather hard for libraries to keep up. Maybe its time that Dart/Polymer to have an official page to document changes so everyone can go there to see it. Currently the changes are in so many different areas, it is hard to track.

Comment: Is this still necessary today? I put it in the index.html and not in the component and seems that it works fine. Is there a counter indication for doing this?

Comment: It's convention. You should do it in each component. When someone uses your component it should behave as expected and it shouldn't be necessary to import it in the entry page.